# Converting string to timespan

Tags: powershell, type-conversion

Im new to powershell and Ive been trying to convert this string to a timespan object:

"2 Days 1 Hour 15 Minutes"

Ive tried several ways to input the format using parseexact but I cant seem to get the right format down.

Ive tried something like this :

```
[TimeSpan]::ParseExact('2 Days 1 Hour 15 Minutes', 'd \Days h \Hour MM \Minutes', $null)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The TimeSpan parser is very sensitive, you need to escape everything that isn't a format string specifier:

```
[TimeSpan]::ParseExact('2 Days 1 Hour 15 Minutes', '%d\ \D\a\y\s\ %h\ \H\o\u\r\ %m\ \M\i\n\u\t\e\s', $null)
```

(I used the percent-sign notation for the specifiers (`%d` instead of `d`) to make them stand out in amongst all the `\`'s, but they're not required)

Comment: Thank you so much for the quick answer. It works perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

The string version normally looks like this: `'2.01:15:00'`, so `[timespan]'2.01:15'` works.

Answer (score 0):

I am glad to see you have an answer. Another way would be to use named captures in a regex.

```
PS C:\> '2 Days 1 Hour 15 Minutes' -match '^(?<Days>\d+)\D*(?<Hours>\d+)\D*(?<Minutes>\d+)\D*'
True
PS C:\> $matches

Name                           Value
----                           -----
Hours                          1
Minutes                        15
Days                           2
0                              2 Days 1 Hour 15 Minutes

PS C:\> $Matches.Days
2
PS C:\> $Matches.Hours
1
PS C:\> $Matches.Minutes
15

PS C:\> $Ts = New-TimeSpan -days $Matches.Days -Hours $Matches.Hours -Minutes $Matches.Minutes
PS C:\> $Ts

Days              : 2
Hours             : 1
Minutes           : 15
Seconds           : 0
Milliseconds      : 0
Ticks             : 1773000000000
TotalDays         : 2.05208333333333
TotalHours        : 49.25
TotalMinutes      : 2955
TotalSeconds      : 177300
TotalMilliseconds : 177300000
```

Answer (score 0):

Be mindful when converting string to`[timespan]`. It will throw an **InvalidCastParseTargetInvocationWithFormatProvider** error if your string is empty.